# Can you use JavaScript as embedded resources with Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, resources

In Asp.Net with Ajax I can include my Javascript files as embedded resources in my assembly and create references to the embedded scripts using the ScriptManager.

Is there a way to do the same with Asp.Net MVC?

Comment: Please as a specific question with related code posted as well so that others may see what you have tried and what has failed. You must have done research and show that result here. Thanks!